# Roll out static folder as plugin and access via domainname.com/anyname

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to roll out static content via a word press plugin. Lets say the folder rolled out is located at domainname.com/wp-content/plugins/pluginname and I would like to access it via domainname.com/pluginname for example.

I have the following quesitons:

1. How would you roll out this folder if you like to have it some kind of installable.
2. How do we solve the access via the desired url?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly, but here is a possible solution.

Create a custom page template in your (child) theme folder by making a file and include that will hook your custom template page to WP. (See [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) for more information) On this page your can basically pull any WordPress functionality that your require.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Name */ ?>
```

Switch on Post Name option in your Permalinks settings for pretty permalinks and then create a new page in WP that will use your newly created template. On that URL you can access the code that you've supplied in the custom page template.